# Sorting ArrayList on collectors function

Tags: sorting, arraylist, collectors

I did the code below to have a dropdown box with all the currencies code.

`List<String> currencies = Currency.getAvailableCurrencies().stream() .map(currency -> currency.getCurrencyCode()) .collect(Collectors.toList());`

However, my output is unsorted.

Someone could give me a hand to sort the ArrayList(Currencies) on the code below?

Appreciate any help =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort by adding `.sorted()` into your stream. This will sort the list on it's natural order

```
List<String> currencies = Currency.getAvailableCurrencies().stream().map(currency -> currency.getCurrencyCode()).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

When you want something more advanced than natural ordering, or you want to order an object, you can simply pass a Comperator as argument to the sorted method.

For example if you want the list to be in reverse order

```
List<String> currencies = Currency.getAvailableCurrencies().stream().map(currency -> currency.getCurrencyCode()).sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked the both options =)

Comment: When I have a list with many attributes, like a table, what is the best way to sort the list by one of the attributes?

This is my list: 
"Result(provider.alias, provider.name, provider.logo, q.rate, q.fee, q.receivedAmount, q.dateCollected);
}).collect(Collectors.toList());"

and I am calling the Result list on this method:

"TransferWiseComparison comparison = mapper.readValue(result.toString(), TransferWiseComparison.class);
        return comparison.toResults();"

I am trying to sort the chart by received amount

Comment: You could use something like .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Result::receivedAmount)) where Result is the class that is being passed on. if the object is deeper, you can always write it like an expression Comparator.comparing(value -> value.getAvailableCurrencies)

Comment: Yoni, thanks again! Really appreciate all your help =)